# Angular directive and control instance variables

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a control in angular. What I would like to do is use some custom directives to build an array of tabs. I have defined the html as follows:

```
<div class="tabber" ng-controller="tabController as tabControllerVM">
<div class="tabber-page-container">
    <div id="jobs-tab" class="tabber-page" tab-page="job queue">
       <p>Job Queue<p>
    </div>
    <div id="watchfolders-tab" class="tabber-page" tab-page="watchfolders">
       <p>Watchfolder tab</p>
    </div>
    <div id="admin-tab" class="tabber-page" tab-page="admin">
       <p>admin</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The directive is tab-page. When this is called I want it to add the value to an array in my controller, which is called tabPages. Once the directives have run, I want the array to contain 'job queue', 'watchfolders', 'admin'

I have set up the angular code as follows:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('tabController', tabController)
    .directive('tabPage', addTabPage)

function tabController() {

    var vm = this;
    vm.tabPages = [];
    vm.addTab = AddTab;

    function AddTab(TabName) {
        vm.tabPages.push(new tab(TabName));
        alert(vm.tabPages.length);
    }
};


function addTabPage() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: "tabController",
        controllerAs: "tabControllerVM",
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, controller) {
            controller.addTab(attr.tabPage);
        }
    }
};
```

})();

Each time a new tab is added, for testing purposes, I'm displaying the number of elements in the array. The problem is that the output is 1,1,1 not 1,2,3 as I would expect. On closer examination, the constructor for the control is being run each time the directive is run which reinitialises all of my variables. I have traced this down to the constructor being called in controller: "tabController". If I remove this line, the constructor is only called once. However, the controller instance in the link method no longer has any initialised variables. Is it possible to carry the control instance over from one directive call to the next? If so how is this achieved?

Many thanks,

Damien

Update

After spending a day developing a service to hold the data, I happened to stumble upon the solution to my original problem. Essentially what I wanted to do is to access the instance of the controller associated with the html elements. This can be achieved easily within the directive using the expression "elem.controller()" which allows you to access the controller instance bound to the UI within the directive. Here it is as part of my directive:

```
function addTabPage() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: "tabController",
        controllerAs: "tabControllerVM",
        scope: false,
        link: {
            post: function postLink(scope, elem, attr, controller) {

                elem.controller().tabs.push(new tab(attr.tabPage, false, elem));

                var tabs = elem.controller().tabs;

                for (var a = 0; a < tabs.length; a++) {
                    if (a != 0) {
                        tabs[a].DeselectTab(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        tabs[a].SelectTab(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Nice and simple and works really well. This allows me to hold some variables within the controller whilst the html is being parsed and rendered to the browser. Hopefully this will help others with the same problem.

Comment: controllers are not singletons, a new controller is always initialized for each copy of a directive.  you should have two different directives here, one for the tab bar itself, and a second for each individual tab.

Comment: How would two directives help me to add objects to a shared array? Essentially what I want to end up with is a populated array (which will be extended to hold the tab name and the html element) once the directives have been called which I can then use to build the UI for the tabs across the top of the screen. I can then hide and show the html tab-page elements when the user clicks on one of the tabs for example.

Comment: the parent directive would be the container that holds the array of tabs, and the child directive(s) would be the directive for the tab behavior.

Comment: Interesting, so if I understand you correctly it's possible to have an array object within a directive or do I misunderstand. Is there any chance you could show me what you mean - I'm a bit confused. I thought directives were just markers to attach event handlers etc.

Comment: Right, so I'm going to change my approach to reflect more accurately MVC methodology. I'm going to create a service that holds the state of all my tab controllers and get the controllers to read the data from there. That way it doesn't matter if a new instance is created, they will still be talking to the same backend data.

Comment: I've found the solution, see the updated question....